# A way to refresh program?

Tags: java, restart

I have a program that reads comma separated lists from a text file, saves it into various arrays and then performs calculations. The calculations along with the data from the text file are displayed in a GUI.

The user has the option to edit some of the data by typing in a TextField. When they click 'Save and Refresh' it should update the calculations and display the new values.

Currently I can overwrite the text file with the new data but I have no way of updating it, other than opening and closing my program.

Is there a way to refresh or restart the program as if I had opened and closed it ?

Thankyou!

Comment: You can try to check if file is changed or not for a particual time say 5 seconds.If file is changed then perform task else dont perform task

Comment: It's not very clear, could you explain it a little better?

Comment: Register the GUI as a listener on the class that does the saving, then notify the GUI when there's a change in the data.

Comment: You probably unfamiliar with MVC concept. Try to google it.